# ARKit ImageDetection - get reference image when tapping 3D object

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to create an App, that detects reference images, then a 3D (SCNScene) object appears (multiple images / objects in 1 Camera is possible). This is already running.

Now, when the user taps on the object, I need to know the file-name of the referenceImage, because the image should be shown.

---

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    private var planeNode: SCNNode?
    private var imageNode: SCNNode?
    private var animationInfo: AnimationInfo?
    private var currentMediaName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Load reference images to look for from "AR Resources" folder
        guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
            fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
        }

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Add previously loaded images to ARScene configuration as detectionImages
        configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(rec:)))
        //Add recognizer to sceneview
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    //Method called when tap
    @objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    //GET Reference-Image Name
        loadReferenceImage()

        if rec.state == .ended {
            let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneView)
            let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
            if !hits.isEmpty{
                let tappedNode = hits.first?.node
            }
        }
    }

    func loadReferenceImage(){
            print("CLICK")
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {
            return
        }
        currentMediaName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name

        // 1. Load plane's scene.
        let planeScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/plane.scn")!
        let planeNode = planeScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "planeRootNode", recursively: true)!

        // 2. Calculate size based on planeNode's bounding box.
        let (min, max) = planeNode.boundingBox
        let size = SCNVector3Make(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y, max.z - min.z)

        // 3. Calculate the ratio of difference between real image and object size.
        // Ignore Y axis because it will be pointed out of the image.
        let widthRatio = Float(imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width)/size.x
        let heightRatio = Float(imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)/size.z
        // Pick smallest value to be sure that object fits into the image.
        let finalRatio = [widthRatio, heightRatio].min()!

        // 4. Set transform from imageAnchor data.
        planeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(imageAnchor.transform)

        // 5. Animate appearance by scaling model from 0 to previously calculated value.
        let appearanceAction = SCNAction.scale(to: CGFloat(finalRatio), duration: 0.4)
        appearanceAction.timingMode = .easeOut
        // Set initial scale to 0.
        planeNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        // Add to root node.
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
        // Run the appearance animation.
        planeNode.runAction(appearanceAction)


        self.planeNode = planeNode
        self.imageNode = node

    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        guard let imageNode = imageNode, let planeNode = planeNode else {
            return
        }

        // 1. Unwrap animationInfo. Calculate animationInfo if it is nil.
        guard let animationInfo = animationInfo else {
            refreshAnimationVariables(startTime: time,
                                      initialPosition: planeNode.simdWorldPosition,
                                      finalPosition: imageNode.simdWorldPosition,
                                      initialOrientation: planeNode.simdWorldOrientation,
                                      finalOrientation: imageNode.simdWorldOrientation)
            return
        }

        // 2. Calculate new animationInfo if image position or orientation changed.
        if !simd_equal(animationInfo.finalModelPosition, imageNode.simdWorldPosition) || animationInfo.finalModelOrientation != imageNode.simdWorldOrientation {

            refreshAnimationVariables(startTime: time,
                                      initialPosition: planeNode.simdWorldPosition,
                                      finalPosition: imageNode.simdWorldPosition,
                                      initialOrientation: planeNode.simdWorldOrientation,
                                      finalOrientation: imageNode.simdWorldOrientation)
        }

        // 3. Calculate interpolation based on passedTime/totalTime ratio.
        let passedTime = time - animationInfo.startTime
        var t = min(Float(passedTime/animationInfo.duration), 1)
        // Applying curve function to time parameter to achieve "ease out" timing
        t = sin(t * .pi * 0.5)

        // 4. Calculate and set new model position and orientation.
        let f3t = simd_make_float3(t, t, t)
        planeNode.simdWorldPosition = simd_mix(animationInfo.initialModelPosition, animationInfo.finalModelPosition, f3t)
        planeNode.simdWorldOrientation = simd_slerp(animationInfo.initialModelOrientation, animationInfo.finalModelOrientation, t)
        //planeNode.simdWorldOrientation = imageNode.simdWorldOrientation

        guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!
        print("TEST")
        print(name)

    }



    func refreshAnimationVariables(startTime: TimeInterval, initialPosition: float3, finalPosition: float3, initialOrientation: simd_quatf, finalOrientation: simd_quatf) {
        let distance = simd_distance(initialPosition, finalPosition)
        // Average speed of movement is 0.15 m/s.
        let speed = Float(0.15)
        // Total time is calculated as distance/speed. Min time is set to 0.1s and max is set to 2s.
        let animationDuration = Double(min(max(0.1, distance/speed), 2))
        // Store animation information for later usage.
        animationInfo = AnimationInfo(startTime: startTime,
                                      duration: animationDuration,
                                      initialModelPosition: initialPosition,
                                      finalModelPosition: finalPosition,
                                      initialModelOrientation: initialOrientation,
                                      finalModelOrientation: finalOrientation)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `ARReferenceImage` is stored within the `Assets.xcassets` catalogue you can simply load your image using the following initialization method of `UIImage`:

```
init?(named name: String)
```

For your information:

> if this is the first time the image is being
>    loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the
>    application’s main bundle. For PNG images, you may omit the filename
>    extension. For all other file formats, always include the filename
>    extension.

In my example I have an `ARReferenceImage` named `TargetCard`:

[image]

So to load it as a `UIImage` and then apply it as an `SCNNode` or display it in `screenSpace` you could so something like so:

```
//1. Load The Image Onto An SCNPlaneGeometry
if let image = UIImage(named: "TargetCard"){

    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
    planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
}

//2. Load The Image Into A UIImageView
if let image = UIImage(named: "TargetCard"){

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 150))
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

In your context:

Each SCNNode has a name property:

```
var name: String? { get set }
```

As such I suggest that when you create content in regard to your `ARImageAnchor` you provide it with the name of your `ARReferenceImage` e.g:

```
//---------------------------
// MARK: -  ARSCNViewDelegate
//---------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have Detected An ARImageAnchor & Check It's The One We Want
        guard let validImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let targetName = validImageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return}

        //2. Create An SCNNode With An SCNPlaneGeometry
        let nodeToAdd = SCNNode()
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
        nodeToAdd.geometry = planeGeometry

        //3. Set It's Name To That Of Our ARReferenceImage
        nodeToAdd.name = targetName

        //4. Add It To The Hierachy
        node.addChildNode(nodeToAdd)

    }
}
```

Then it is easy to get a reference to the Image later e.g:

```
/// Checks To See If We Have Hit A Named SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    let currentTouchLocation = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. Perform An SCNHitTest To See If We Have Tapped A Valid SCNNode & See If It Is Named
    guard let hitTestForNode = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, options: nil).first?.node,
          let nodeName = hitTestForNode.name else { return }

    //3. Load The Reference Image
    self.loadReferenceImage(nodeName, inAR: true)
}

/// Loads A Matching Image For The Identified ARReferenceImage Name
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - fileName: String
///   - inAR: Bool
func loadReferenceImage(_ fileName: String, inAR: Bool){

    if inAR{

        //1. Load The Image Onto An SCNPlaneGeometry
        if let image = UIImage(named: fileName){

            let planeNode = SCNNode()
            let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
            planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
            planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry
            planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
            self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }

    }else{

        //2. Load The Image Into A UIImageView
        if let image = UIImage(named: fileName){

            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 150))
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

}
```

**Important:**

One thing I have just discovered is that if we load the the `ARReferenceImage` e.g:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "TargetCard")
```

Then the image is displayed is in `GrayScale`, which is properly what you dont want!

As such what you probably need to do is to copy the `ARReferenceImage` into the `Assets Catalogue` and give it a `prefix` e.g. ColourTargetCard...

Then you would need to change the function slightly by naming your nodes using a prefix e.g:

```
nodeToAdd.name = "Colour\(targetName)"
```

[image]

Hope it helps...